# Executing list of tasks in chain

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of tasks like pre-run validations, execute, post-run to be executed in chain and result of task have to be passed on to next task. Is there any python library provides this functionality out of box ?

I looked up following python libraries, but they are heavy-weight.

1. celery
2. luigi

Comment: _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_ is off-topic.

Comment: [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). [Don't advise on off-topic questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/)

Answer (score 1):

What requirement prevents you from writing that list of tasks in a single script and running it?

Sometimes simplest is the best; do not over-complicate things unless there's a specific requirement (and if you do have a specific requirement, you'll need to keep that in mind while evaluating solutions).